# How to Zoom in multi-axes in the same time in matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide, zooming, roi

I have a GUI with two axes. The first one for original image while the second one is for interpolated image.

First in my code, I use *imrect* to select part of the original image and then I crop that part using *imcrop* . After that I display the cropped image in both axes.

What I want is to know how to zoom in the first axes (the original image)  and it shows the same zooming the second axes ( interpolated image ) automatically.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear the relationship between the two actions you mention in your question:

- using `imrect` and `imcrop` to work on the image
- zooming on one axes and have the same zoom on the second

A possible solution to automatically apply the zoom made on the first axes to the second one could be using the `linkaxes` built-in function.

If in your GUI you have two axex with, respectively, `tag` axes1 and axes2, you can add the following statements in the GUI `OpeningFcn`

```
linkaxes([handles.axes1 handles.axes2])
```

This allows automatically applying the zoom you make on axes1 also to axes2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help, it works perfectly. I will explain to you the relationship, the original image is very huge, so that I choose part of it and then crop it show it in both axes. After that I would like to zoom on that part (original) and have the same zoom on the second axes by using Linkaxes that you told me to use. Thus thank you a lot.